# JS Weak Map cannot deduce equality on free objects - Hacking a keyvalue pipe for WeakMap

Tags: angular, typescript

The tl;dr of the core problem is `WeakMap.get()` returns `undefined` if the key object is not referenced by a `variable/let` in the global scope (scope of the Angular Component in this case)

**The MRE:**

```
    let x = new WeakMap()
    x.set({month: 1, date: 15, year: 2015}, {month: 1, date: 15, year:2015})
    console.log(x.get({month: 1, date: 15, year: 2015}))
```

This prints **undefined**

So does this

```
    let x = new WeakMap()
    let d = {month: 1, date: 15, year: 2015}
    x.set(d, {month: 1, date: 15, year:2015})
    console.log(x.get({month: 1, date: 15, year: 2015}))
```

The only way of getting it to work is set AND get by the same reference:

```
    let x = new WeakMap()
    let d = {month: 1, date: 15, year: 2015}
    x.set(d, {month: 1, date: 15, year:2015})
    console.log(d)
```

Which doesn't work in the following code, because the `let` is individually scoped on every iteration of `reduce`

```
  this.grouped_messages = this.current_conversation.messsages.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.date) > 
      new Date(b.date)) ? 1 : -1).reduce((agg, item) => {
      let date = new Date(item.date)
      let group = {month: date.getMonth(), date: date.getDate(), year: date.getFullYear()};
      agg.set(group, [...(agg.get(group) || []), item])
      return agg
    }, new WeakMap())
```

I am fully aware of the referential equality vs equality of objects by value but How can I work around this issue? I am building a wrapper around `WeakMap` to introduce iterability, similar to [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs#iterable-weakmaps) in order to enable Angular's `keyvalue` pipe to be able to accept a WeakMap, thus clients need to be able to pass in objects they have constructed themselves and get the same results

Comment: JSON.stringify the object and use the string as the key. Not foolproof, but should be close. Also, no point in using a WeakMap if you aren't using references. Just use a POJO with the JSON stringified keys.

Comment: @JaredSmith I know.. the docs specifically say that keys are weakly referenced. It's not that I don't want to use them, it is the way references are allocated inside the reduce. They get GCed immediately. I guess I have no other option than to fall back to the string representation. Thanks anyway!